# Disable Interrupt in C program

Tags: c, arm, interrupt, keil

How do i disable the interrupt in this ARM M0 univesity design start program? 
The design is made for the M0 and echos an inputted char as an integer, it is part of a larger piece of code (which is ommitted for simplicity)
Can i do it in the main program(attached) or will i have to edit the assembler code(also attached)?

```
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Cortex-M0 DesignStart C program example
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <rt_misc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define AHB_LED_BASE                0x50000000
#define AHB_UART_BASE               0x51000000


void UART_ISR(void)
{
            int sample;
            char ch [16];
            sample = atoi (ch);
            printf("the value entered is %d\n", sample);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main Function
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main() 
    {

        char ch [16];
        while(1==1)
        {
        fgets (ch, 16, stdin);
    //printf("String: %s\n\n",ch);
        }
}
```

Assembly code

```
UART_Handler    PROC
                EXPORT UART_Handler
                IMPORT UART_ISR
                PUSH    {R0,R1,R2,LR}
                LDR     R1, =0x51000000               ;UART
                LDR     R0, [R1]                      ;Get Data from UART
                STR     R0, [R1]                      ;Write to UART

                BL UART_ISR

                POP     {R0,R1,R2,PC}
                ENDP


                ALIGN 4
```

Comment: What research have you done in finding '*How to disable interrupts?*'.  Can you supply a reference manual and/or other source that you have looked at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use CMSIS drivers, check for:

1. `void __disable_irq(void)`
2. `void __enable_irq(void)`

They just call `CPSIE` and `CPSID` instructions.

Generally read about `NVIC` in the programming manual. I also recommend a fantastic book on Cortex M0:

*The Definitive Guide to the ARM Cortex-M0* by Joseph Yiu.

Answer (score 0):

If u wish to write a simple code in ASM, you can simply store and raise the BASEPRI to a higher priority than all the NVIC's (besides, say, exception type debugMon), do what u need todo and than restore the original BASEPRI